# Calculating totals from formulas that represent different groups

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

I have a Crystal Report that shows different groups(or departments) utilizing the groups in Crystal Reports.  I then used some formulas to calculate Attached and Unattached assets in each group. Now I wish to show a total for the column of Attached and Unattached, what is the best and simplest way to do this?

Update
Okay I have been able to use a running total on @countattached that gets me close to what I need, the only problem is that it wants to add the last group total to the next group.  The report is set up so the **Employee** (I.E. Jane Doe) and under that **Employees** name are **Groups** that, that **Employee** adds reports too such as **Parks, Water, Streets , Etc**.  those **Groups** have a field across from them for **Attached** and **Unattached** with a total for both together at the end for each Group.  I need a total for each **Group** under the column of attached and Unattached..

[CrystalReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IgcQ.jpg)

Comment: What have your tried so far and found not working?

Comment: I have tried to use this formula "(Count({@CountAttached});({WORKORDER.INITIATEDBY})" to get a total for attached and/or Unattached but it only shows the Person who it was initiated by.  I am wanting it to give me a total based on the person in question.

Comment: Would it be enough just create a summarize field of @CountAttached? Right click on the field @CountAttached, insert, summary...

Comment: @heringer when I do a summarize on the CountAttached the values do not add up to the correct amount.  I'm not sure what is causing the sum to be more than it should be. I thought it was adding the attached and unattached together but that doesn't seem to be the case.  
   The "CountAttached" formula looks like this "if {WORKORDER.UNATTACHED}='N' then 1 else 0" and the CountUnattached formula looks like this "if {WORKORDER.UNATTACHED}='Y' then 1 else 0.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally figured it out if you have a series of columns that have sums for individual groups(parks,streets,water) under employees all you need to do to calculate the totals of those groups is right take the formula that has the sum for those groups, , such as (@countAttached). Then do a **Running Total** in the Running total dialog box, you can then set it to reset after each individual that those groups apply to then you have a those totals for that column. You just repeat this process for any other Columns you have.